# Why do references to Function.prototype functions not work

Tags: javascript

Why does the second case not working?

```
// 1. works
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call({a:1}, 'a');

// 2. does not work
var hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call;
hasProp({a:1}, 'a');
```

http://jsbin.com/ramenaxame/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that all functions share the same [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method, inherited from [`Function.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Function_prototype_object).

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call === Function.prototype.call // true
```

When you call `call` on a function, that function becomes the `this` value for `call`, so `call` can call the function. This is the case of your first code, which works.

However, in your second code, you don't call `call` as a method of an object. Therefore, its `this` value will be `undefined` in strict mode, or the global object in non-strict mode. Neither `undefined` nor the global object are callable, so `call` will throw.

In fact, your code is equivalent to

```
var hasProp = Function.prototype.call;
hasProp({a:1}, 'a');
```

As you can see, there is no reference to [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), so it can't work.

You can fix that using `call` to call `call` with `hasOwnProperty` as the `this` value:

```
var call = Function.prototype.call;
call.call(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, {a:1}, 'a');
```

But a better idea would be creating a new function that behaves like `call` but has its `this` value bound to `hasOwnProperty`. You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to achieve this:

```
var hasProp = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);
hasProp({a:1}, 'a');
```

Comment: lol, basically what I'm seeing is ``call.call(...)``. That's kind of amusing.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment.  This works fine. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can detach the method in this way to make it work:

```
var hasProp = Function.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty)
```

Comment: <pedantry> Just so it's said, `bind` is kinda the _opposite_ of "detaching", hence the name.  The function you get back carries its `this` around with it, so in a sense it is even more tied to a particular object.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment.  This works fine. +1